# keep small change to js library through updates

Tags: javascript, version-control

I am using a javascript library called [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked).  I made a few small changes to the code to customize something (I wanted `__`this`__` to underline stuff instead of bolding it).

What is the best way to deal with the issue of keeping the library up-to-date in my project over time?  It may be a hassle to manually add my change every time I update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a branch of marked for your changes.  this would be where you could put your customizations.  then when the marked library is updated and you are ready to integrate their changes into yours you would migrate their changes into your branch and merge their code into yours.  if they ever manage to fix the thing that you made you changes for, then you can always switch to the main branch.

Comment: So create my own GitHub repository which is just a branch of marked?

Comment: Yes. you will need to have / create a GitHub account to branch it on GitHub though. If you don't mind having your customizations public, then you can go with the free GitHub account. otherwise you would need to do a paid account or just host the Git repository somewhere else.

Even if you put the repository somewhere else, you can always merge the marked code from GitHub into your other git repository